# Clarification of a Probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistical-inference

Suppose I have two continuous, non-negative random variables, $X$ and $Y$ and I have that 
$$ P(X) = P(X|Y)\cdot P(Y).  $$

Can I go on and say that $$ P(X\gt z) = P(X\gt z | Y\gt z)\cdot P(Y\gt z) = P(X\gt z, Y\gt z)?$$

---

I'd also appreciate it if someone could come up with a better title.

Comment: You can say $P(X>z|Y>z)\cdot P(Y>z)=P(X >z\cap X>z)$. But why should it be the same as $P(X>z)$ ?

Comment: The first line you have already is vague and contain error. Suppose you mean those functions are the pdf, the LHS is the marginal pdf of $X$ but the RHS is the joint pdf of $X, Y$. So similar to callculus comment above.

Comment: P(Y) = 1, I think...

Comment: @callculus I am confused how $P(X>z|Y>z).P(Y>z)=P(X>z \cap X>z)$? Should it not be $P(X>z|Y>z).P(Y>z)=P(X>z \cap Y>z)$ in you comment. If I am wrong then I will be very grateful if you can clarify me how its true. Thank you.

Comment: @FrankMoses Yes, it should be like you have written. It was a typo. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @callculus Is there no condition under which it could be the same as $P(X\gt z)?$

Comment: well maybe when both $X,Y$ are independent random variables and $P(Y>z)=1$ then the above equation can be true in my view

Answer (score 2):

There is a slight misstep in notation often given with the conditional probability rule. In particular,

$$P(X) = P(X|Y)P(Y)$$

intuitively assumes that we are conditioning upon the entire support of $Y$ ($S_Y$), and assuming $Y$ is a discrete random variable (the continuous case can dealt with similarly), we can see that the more appropriate notation would be

$$P(X) = \sum_{Y \in S_Y} P(X,Y) = \sum_{Y \in S_Y} P(X|Y)P(Y).$$

Hence, you will need to be more careful with defining what values $z$ can take on in the following statement.

Comment: +1 for stressing the need of appropriate notations, but -1 for the formula that comes just after that, *which is horrible*. What you might have in mind is probably $$P(X=x) = \sum_{y\in S_Y} P(X=x,Y=y) = \sum_{y\in S_Y} P(X=x|Y=y)P(Y=y).$$